# How to check userid in table before inserting userid and password into tables in node.js?

Tags: android, sql, node.js, ibm-cloud

Am creating android app, that connects to SQLDB database and am inserting username, userid and password into table. Before inserting into table i have check the userId already existing in the table if not then i have to insert.
and how to callback response "registration successful" if inserted correctly or "userid already exist" to my android app.

This is my node.js code:

```
  var express   = require('express');
app         = express();
var ibmbluemix  = require('ibmbluemix') 
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var logger = ibmbluemix.getLogger();

var PORT = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8000);
var HOST = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');

var queryData = null;

var serviceName = 'SQLDB';

if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
db2 = env['sqldb'][0].credentials;
}
else{
console.error("INFORMATION FOR DB CONNECTION NOT FOUND");
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be adding a userid yourself to be honest, doesn't your user column have auto increment on the id? Also I don't really see what your insert query is, or am I missing something?

Comment: this is my insert query:
INSERT INTO  USER02130.USER_DETAILS (FULL_NAME, PASSWORD,SHORT_ID) values('" +  strNameTxt +"', " +strPasswdTxt +","+strEmailTxt +");
first i have to check user existance in table, then i will insert into table.

Comment: so you want to see if the short_id already exists?

Comment: yes, first i have to check user exists if not then i will insert into table

Comment: "select * from table where short_id = yourvaluehere"  if that returns a row, your user id already exists, if it doesn't you can do your insert

Comment: Jeremey C's comment should really be an answer as it answers the OP handily.

Comment: @SanthoshS are you sitll  having an issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use autogenerated ids instead of creating them, for example using autoincrement or sequences.
Anyway, you could simply use a simple query checking the id is already in use by

```
SELECT ID FROM USER02130.USER_DETAILS WHERE ID = <ID>
```

and if it returns a value you can return an error to your application, otherwise you can then run the insert query 
INSERT INTO USER02130.USER_DETAILS () VALUES (
and return the id (for example) with a success code.
You can also customize the return codes, if you want, and so on.